# Подсчет одинаковых элементов массива

Tags: php

Доброго времени всем, пожалуйста, подскажите, кому не лень, на примере...

Если КОРОТКО: есть массив данных:

```
01.09.2016|10:48:31|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером  прервана.
01.09.2016|10:48:32|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером  прервана.
01.09.2016|10:48:36|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером  прервана.
01.09.2016|16:41:34|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером  прервана.
01.09.2016|18:47:06|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером  прервана.
```

Эксплодим по полям массива и получаем набор IP ниже по коду `$fields[2]`, получаем набор IP адресов.

ВОПРОС: как узнать количество всех одинаковых IP, сколько 192.168.0.1, а сколько 192.168.0.2 ???

Насколько представляю себе, то: `array_count_values()`, как реализовать?

Comment: Правильную функцию вы уже нашли, дальше дело за малым. Что **конкретно** не получается сделать? Где код вашей попытки?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обойтись без explode, чтения по строкам и т.д. достаточно сделать так:

```
$str = ...;
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/.*\|.*\|(.*)\|.*/', $str, $matches);
$ipCountMap = array_count_values($returnValue[1]);
```

Comment: а какова будет по вашему эффективность работы регулярных выражений на больших файлах по сравнению с построковым чтением?

Comment: Естественно зависит от размера файла. Но на больших файлах я бы так эту задачу вообще не решал - файл всё ещё надо прочесть. Если речь идёт об обработке больших объёмов постоянно появляющихся логов можно поднять какую-нибудь time-series database наподобие unflux и хранить логи в ней (если позже по этим логам предполагается какая-либо аналитика). Если же единственное что нужно это задача озвученная ТС - то я бы использовал что-то вроде awk

Comment: `$str =  "awk -F \"|\" '{print $2}' file.csv";`  и далее explode и подсчёт

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
$ips = [];
foreach ($rows as $fields) {
    $ips[] = $fields[2];
}
$ipCountMap = array_count_values($ips);

// echo '<pre>'; print_r($ipCountMap); die;
//
// Array
// (
//     [192.168.0.1] => 3
//     [192.168.0.2] => 2
// )
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php
$arr = [ 
    '01.09.2016|10:48:31|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана', 
    '01.09.2016|10:48:32|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана', 
    '01.09.2016|10:48:36|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана', 
    '01.09.2016|16:41:34|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером прервана', 
    '01.09.2016|18:47:06|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером прервана' 
];

$ips = array_map(function($v) {
    $t = explode('|', $v);
    return $t[2];
}, $arr);

$map = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    if (!isset($map[$ips[$i]])) {
        $map[$ips[$i]] = [];
    }
    $map[$ips[$i]][] = $arr[$i];
}

$totals = array_map('count', $map);

print_r($map);
print_r($totals);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [192.168.0.1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01.09.2016|10:48:31|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана
            [1] => 01.09.2016|10:48:32|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана
            [2] => 01.09.2016|10:48:36|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана
        )

    [192.168.0.2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01.09.2016|16:41:34|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером прервана
            [1] => 01.09.2016|18:47:06|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером прервана
        )

)
Array
(
    [192.168.0.1] => 3
    [192.168.0.2] => 2
)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/371cbd265de9487763d391d51631e1a7a79e88bd

Comment: Спасибо большое, у меня есть пример вот такой:

Comment: $arr = [
    '01.09.2016|10:48:31|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана',
    '01.09.2016|10:48:32|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана',
    '01.09.2016|10:48:36|192.168.0.1|Cвязь с сервером прервана',
    '01.09.2016|16:41:34|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером прервана',
    '01.09.2016|18:47:06|192.168.0.2|Cвязь с сервером прервана'
];
 
// Искомый IP
$srch = '192.168.0.1';
 
$matches = array_filter($arr, function ($item) use ($srch) {
    return preg_match('~'. preg_quote($srch) .'~', $item);
});

Comment: if (!empty($matches)) {
    $view = 'Всего ошибок: <b>'. count($matches) .'</b><hr />'.
        '<table border="1" style="background-color:#EEE5AE;">'.
        '<th>Дата</th><th>Время</th><th>IP</th><th>Сообщение</th>';
 
    foreach ($matches as $i => $v) {
        list($date, $time, $ip, $mesg) = explode('|', $v);
        $view .= ($i & 1 ? '<tr>' : '<tr style="background-color:#EEEEE0;">')
            . '<td>'. $date .'</td><td>'. $time .'</td><td>'. $ip .'</td><td>'
            . $mesg .'</td></tr>';
    }

Comment: $view .= '</table>';
} else {
    $view = 'Ошибок связи по IP: <b>'. $srch .'</b> не обнаружено!<br />';
}
 
echo $view;

Comment: А как вывести для каждого IP? Да еще и привязанным к именам, 192.168.0.1 => Офис 1, 
192.168.0.1 => Офис 2, чтобы в итоге выводило, Офис 1 всего ошибок - 25, Офис 2 - всего ошибок -10

Comment: @AlexPebody Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: @AlexPebody, у вас в коде не хватает открывающего тега <tr>.

Comment: @AlexPebody, добавил к ответу